# How to update collection and view with new data from response?

Tags: backbone.js, coffeescript, backbone-views

How to update posts collection with new data from server in `handleSliderChange()`? When I'm trying to use `fetch()` in `$.getJSON` collection is reseted with old data.

```
define ['jquery','backbone','app','views/posts/post_view','templates/posts/index'], 
($, Backbone, App, PostsView) ->
  class App.Views.Posts.IndexView extends Backbone.View
    template: JST["posts/index"]

    events:
      "slidechange #slider":   "handleSliderChange"

    initialize: () ->
      @options.posts.on('reset', @render, @)

    addAll: () ->
      @options.posts.each(@addOne, this)

    addOne: (post) ->
      view = new PostView({model: post})
      $(@el).find("#list").append(view.render().el)

    slider: ->
      $(@el).find("#slider").slider({})

    handleSliderChange: (e, ui) ->
      self = this
      $.getJSON "/posts?scope="+ui.value, (data) ->
        #how to update posts collection with 'data'?

    render: ->
      $(@el).html(@template(posts: @options.posts.toJSON()))
      @slider()
      @addAll()
      @
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Collection.reset`](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-reset) to replace an existing collection with new models.  Assuming that the response from "/posts?scope?ui" is an array of hashes, you would use:

```
$.getJSON "/posts?scope="+ui.value, (data) ->
    self.collection.reset data
```

Note that [`Collection.fetch`](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-fetch) is sort of like calling "getJSON" followed by "reset", so you may want to consider using that instead.

```
options = {}
options["url"] = "/posts?scope="+ui.value
@collection.fetch options
```

Comment: Thanks for second option it is much better :)